# Accessing Dynamic Members on "this"

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic

I have a class, lets name it DynamicBase, which looks basically like this:

```
public class DynamicBase: DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(System.Dynamic.GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
         // doing some magic stuff here, to read Dynamic Properties from this object
    }
}
```

I can use an Instance of this class like

```
dynamic blah = new DynamicBase();
Console.WriteLine(blah.FooProperty);
```

Now I also have a Child Class call DynamicChild which is compiled at runtime and is supposed to access Dynamic Properties. The Generated class Basically would look something like this:

```
public class DynamicChild: DynamicBase
{
    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FooProperty)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make this code compile (since the DynamicBase implements DynamicObject, there would be a mechanism to access FooProperty)?

Comment: If you *know* that your code will require `FooProperty` on that class, why not just implement it normally?

Comment: `((dynamic)this).FooProperty` perhaps?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: As Stated in the post above, the class DynamicChild is compiled at runtime. And it would be just easyer (call me lazy :) ) if i would not have to generate all the properties on that object but could just take them from a baseClass that can provide them.

Comment: @leppie That would definitly work, but i would like to have a possibility to access the properties "just-like-that", whithout having to generate them or having to full-qualify them like that.

Comment: You can't access them without specifying that you want to do it in a dynamic context. The cast to `dynamic` is the only way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @Lasse I was hoping that it would work without explicitly saying dynamic, but that's ok... Thanks anyway

Comment: Unfortunately, creating a class that inherits from DynamicObject only means it can be used in a dynamic context, to actually use it dynamically you need to use it in a dynamic context, and this is not automatic. As such, the cast is needed when you're in a non-dynamic context, to force it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.

Inheriting from `DynamicObject` only adds some extra plumbing for the type so that it can add things dynamically, which can be used in a dynamic context.

However, to actually use those things that were added dynamically, you need to use an object of the type in a dynamic context.

The code you have:

```
public void DoSomeStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine(FooProperty)
}
```

does not use `dynamic`, and thus is not in a dynamic context, the compiler will therefore attempt to compile this statically.

The only way to force a dynamic context is to cast to `dynamic`, as [@leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15541/leppie) said in his comment:

```
public void DoSomeStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)this).FooProperty)
}
```